# Can't require custom module from renderer in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, electron, commonjs

I'm trying to make some classes that I can import for use in my project, but I'm having some trouble actually importing the modules I'm making.

My File Structure looks like this:

```
├╴main.js
└╴src/
   ├╴html/
   │  └╴index.html
   ├╴css/
   │  └╴index.css
   └╴js/
      ├╴index.js
      └╴participant.js
```

All the `index.*` files are related to each other, hence having the same name.

The trouble-makers in question are `index.js`, my renderer for `index.html`, and `participant.js`

Here's the code I got:

```
// index.js
const {Participant} = require("./participant");

const addNodeBtn = document.getElementById('add-node');

addNodeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // this is really just filler code to see if everything works
  let p = new Participant("Jason");
  alert(`His name was ${p.name}`);
});
```

and

```
// participant.js
"use strict";

var Participant = class {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

module.exports.Participant = Participant;
```

For whatever reason I keep getting the error "cannot find module ./participant".

Here's the alternatives I've tried:

```
require("participant");
require("./participant.js");
module.exports = Participant;
module.exports.Participant = class { ... }
```

All to no avail, all give me the same error. I've even renamed `index.js` to something else, thinking it was clashing with the `require` mechanism. Still no change.

Any help on fixing this?

**UPDATE** It seems to be working from within my `main.js` file.

Comment: How are you loading `index.js` in `index.html`?

Comment: @VadimMacagon with the script tag

Comment: Well, turns out *index.js* once included through a script tag resolves its current location to the location of the including HTML code. As such, to require *participant.js*, given your folder structure, you will have to use `require('../js/participant.js')`. This only affects scripts included in HTML pages using the `<script>` tag. All other `require`'s will work as expected.

Comment: @Archy that comment solved it for me. Can you post it as an answer? Because it really is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, turns out *index.js* once included through a script tag resolves its current location to the location of the including HTML code. As such, to require *participant.js*, given your folder structure, you will have to use `require('../js/participant.js')`. This only affects scripts included in HTML pages using the `<script>` tag. All other `require`'s will work as expected.

Comment: and if it was included with `<script>require('module')</script>`?